# Simply trying to multiple a variable in PHP. ($Var * 0.75)

Tags: php, variables, math, int, multiplication

So I am a beginner learning HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and now just starting with PHP, since its the only language to solve my problem.

I have added a Hit Counter on my website which will update a log.txt file by +1 every time I get a new visitor, and also prints/echos it on the page.

I would like to have PHP do some math with the number of visitors. I wish for 2 things to print.

- The first thing is the visitor count (working).
- The second is a simple math formula (Visitor Count * $0.75), which prints/echos "$xx.xx Saved" (not working)

No matter what I try, I always get a print of the formula not the answer. I am assuming this is because I am trying to multiple a string, but can't seem to fix it.

I have tried using:
- settype to change the string to an int.

```
<?php

// Add correct path to your countlog.txt file.
$path = 'hit_counter_log.txt';

// Opens hit_counter_log.txt to read the number of hits.
$file  = fopen( $path, 'r' );
$count = fgets( $file, 1000 );
$money = 0.75;
fclose( $file );

// Update the count.
$count = abs( intval( $count ) ) + 1;

// Output the updated count.
echo "{$count} Views\n";
echo "{$count + $money} Saved";

// Opens hit_counter_log.txt to change new hit number.
$file = fopen( $path, 'w' );
fwrite( $file, $count );
fclose( $file );
```

Assuming my visitor account is 100, I am receiving the print out:
100 + 0.75

I would like it to print: $7,500

Comment: [echo $count + $money . " Saved";](https://3v4l.org/XfkQa) Your math is wrong, too. 100 + .75 = 100.75

Comment: See **Arithmetic Operators**: [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Answer (score 1):

By placing variables inside brackets, it simply prints the value of those variables.  You can't perform operations on variables inside brackets like that.

```
echo "$" . $count + $money . " Saved";
```

... will print out "$100.75 Saved".  As far as how to get it to print out the desired "$7,500", I'll leave the math up to you.  :)

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution was so simple, but I could not figure it out. 

As for the math, I mistakenly added 2 extra zeros lol. 100*0.75=$75 (correct answer) and your fix calcualted the correct answer $75.

Comment: You're welcome!  If you could please click the "solved" button for this answer, the question will be closed.